# nodejs asynchronous to synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm new to nodejs and javascript and I'm currently working on an open source project, since last night I was trying to convert this function from asynchronous to synchronous, but I couldn't, I used async / await but I think that I didn't understand this concept very well, this function encrypts and compresses files using the aes256 algorithm, I works well asynchronously but I want to add this new feature that allows you to encrypt a directory's content recursively.

```
function encrypt({ file, password }, error_callback, succ_callback) {
    const initVect = crypto.randomBytes(16);

    // Generate a cipher key from the password.
    const CIPHER_KEY = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password).digest();;
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    const gzip = zlib.createGzip();
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', CIPHER_KEY, initVect);
    const appendInitVect = new AppendInitVect(initVect);
    // Create a write stream with a different file extension.
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(file + ".dnc"));

    readStream
      .pipe(gzip)
      .pipe(cipher)
      .pipe(appendInitVect)
      .pipe(writeStream);

    readStream.on('error', error_callback);
    readStream.on('end', succ_callback);
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you going to achieve? do you want to write this function using async/await syntax? or you want to make a change in functionality?

Comment: For your project i would suggest you to work with Promises. [This](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) may fit your requirements.

Comment: `async/await` does not serve to make things run synchronously. Any way, forget the idea to make your function synchronous; instead stick with the asynchronous pattern (which may involve `async/await`).

Comment: @MohammadGanji I want to write a function that encrypt files recursively, executes another function when the encryption process is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using promises. By changing the code slightly you can promisify the function and then wait for all promises to resolve or reject before taking action.

```
function encrypt({ file, password }) {
  const initVect = crypto.randomBytes(16);

// Generate a cipher key from the password.
  const CIPHER_KEY = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password).digest();;
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  const gzip = zlib.createGzip();
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', CIPHER_KEY, initVect);
  const appendInitVect = new AppendInitVect(initVect);
// Create a write stream with a different file extension.
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(file + ".dnc"));

  readStream
    .pipe(gzip)
    .pipe(cipher)
    .pipe(appendInitVect)
    .pipe(writeStream);


  const promise = new Promise();
  writeStream.on('error', err => promise.reject(err));
  writeStream.on('end', data => promise.resolve(data));
  return promise;
}

const promise1 = encrypt({file1, password1});
const promise2 = encrypt({file2, password2});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
  .then(succ_callback)
  .catch(error_callback);
```

I have not run this code so it might need some tweaking to make it work, but this is the general gist.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to encrypt the files synchronously, you can do it asynchronously as well. To traverse a directory and get its files use [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) recursively until you can't find any more files, and then you can run `encrypt` on every file found.

Comment: Yeah I did that and it worked fine, But I have a logging function that tells me when the files are successfully encrypted, I used callbacks for encrypting one single files, but in this feature the logger tells that the files are fully encrypted, but they are still in processing (the files sizes is changing)

Comment: PS: I used async / await, and I think that the logger doesnt work synchronously, so it calls the encrypt function and log "all files are encrypted"

Comment: @KRYPT0N Try returning a promise from `encrypt()`, as @Damo has suggested in his answer. You can then await it before you log `all files are encrypted`.